# Operation State Not Thread Safe Swift

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I have subclassed `Operation` to support async operations.
The new class called `AsyncOperation` and added new field called `state`
which is an `enum` to help manage the operation state.

```
class AsyncOperation: Operation {
// DONE: State enum with keyPath property
enum State: String {
   case Ready, Executing, Finished

fileprivate var keyPath: String {
  return "is" + rawValue
  }
}

// DONE: state property
var state = State.Ready {
  willSet {
    willChangeValue(forKey: newValue.keyPath)
    willChangeValue(forKey: state.keyPath)
  }
  didSet {
  didChangeValue(forKey: oldValue.keyPath)
  didChangeValue(forKey: state.keyPath)
  }
 }
}




 extension AsyncOperation {
 // DONE: Operation Overrides
 override var isReady: Bool {
 return super.isReady && state == .Ready
 }

 override var isExecuting: Bool {
    return state == .Executing
 }

 override var isFinished: Bool {
   return state == .Finished
 }

 override var isAsynchronous: Bool {
  return true
 }

 override func start() {
  if isCancelled {
  state = .Finished
  return
 }
 main()
 state = .Executing
 }

override func cancel() {
   state = .Finished
 }

}
```

in general this subclass operates great and im very happy with it.
Im experiencing some odd behaviour tough...
In some cases im adding an operation to the queue like so:

```
//this code happens in mainViewController

//op is an operation that belong to mainViewController and could dispatched to the queue from many places, its init called once in view did load. 
op = SomeAsyncOperation()


if(op.state == .Executing){
  queue.addOperatiom(op)
}
```

and the app crashes because the operation somehow already dispatched to the queue, when i check with breakpoint the `state` property that i have created is `Ready` and the `isExecuting` field of the raw operation is `true`. what happen is my `state` property and the operation state fields are not synced. if i check the `state` field in different implementation it does get to `Executing` and `Finished` how can i be sure those will always be synced?

Answer (score 4):

You should use a NSLock to guard reads and writes to the `state` property.

Take a look a the sample code of the session [Advanced NSOperation](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/226/) from WWDC 2015

The important part is :

```
/// Private storage for the `state` property that will be KVO observed.
private var _state = State.Initialized

/// A lock to guard reads and writes to the `_state` property
private let stateLock = NSLock()

private var state: State {
    get {
        return stateLock.withCriticalScope {
            _state
        }
    }

    set(newState) {
        /*
            It's important to note that the KVO notifications are NOT called from inside
            the lock. If they were, the app would deadlock, because in the middle of
            calling the `didChangeValueForKey()` method, the observers try to access
            properties like "isReady" or "isFinished". Since those methods also
            acquire the lock, then we'd be stuck waiting on our own lock. It's the
            classic definition of deadlock.
        */
        willChangeValueForKey("state")

        stateLock.withCriticalScope { Void -> Void in
            guard _state != .Finished else {
                return
            }

            assert(_state.canTransitionToState(newState), "Performing invalid state transition.")
            _state = newState
        }

        didChangeValueForKey("state")
    }
}
```